# $Y$ is not complete $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Prove that if $Y$ is not complete, then $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is not complete.

$X,Y$ are normed spaces, $\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ is space of bounded linear operators between $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ without a limit. Pick a non-zero vector $f\in X^*$ and set $T_n x = y_n \langle f,x\rangle$. Then $(T_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence without a limit.

Comment: For picking a non-zero vector $f\in X^*$, we need to use the Hahn-Banach theorem. Is there any other method by which one can prove it without using the Hahn-Banach theorem? In the book "Linear Analysis" by Bela Bollobas, this is given as an exercise before they disscuss linear functionals and the Hahn-Banach theorem. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: @Anupam, not really, if $X$ is a dense subspace of a Banach space with trivial dual that exists in a certain model of ZF where the Hahn-Banach theorem fails:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2613391/17929

then certainly $X^*=\{0\}$ is complete.

Comment: @ Tomasz Kania, Thanks for the link. I understood that. Now is it possible to do it without considering a non-trivial bounded linear functional?